# Are sample utterances for AWS Lex case sensitive or punctuation sensitive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm creating a chatbot and I'm adding sample utterances for the intent. I was wondering if there is any case sensitivity for the sample utterances or does punctuations matter? In other words, are the following sample utterances any different to Lex?

- "I'm trying to update my account information"
- "Im trying to update my account information"
- "im trying to update my account information"

Comment: I have not tried yet. I'm creating 1500 utterances for each intent at the moment. You can imagine that this is important to know but there is no indication anywhere in the documents.

Comment: I tried a sample lex bot with those 3 utterances and all worked just fine.  See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for trying it! my question is, do I actually need those three utterances or only one of them would be enough?

Comment: Updated my answer below and as you can see, no you don't need to include all 3.  Granted there might be some edge cases where you might but for these, no.

Comment: In the second example, it seems that Lex could not understand the utterance with only one sample utterance, right?

Answer (score 0):

So I created a sample Lex bot with your 3 sample utterances and they all worked just fine.

[image]

And of course if you remove the utterances that take into account case and punctuation, it still works. The natural language processor is smart enough to handle this sorta thing.

[image]